# errors when trying to set column of record with INTO clause

Tags: oracle, plsql

Hi when I try to compile the procedure below I always receive errors It works when I replace
`TYPE NameCombine IS RECORD(FIRST_NAME employees.FIRST_NAME%TYPE, LAST_NAME  employees.LAST_NAME%TYPE, Combined_NAME employees.LAST_NAME%TYPE);`
with `first_name employees.first_name%TYPE;` and use `where rownum=1` in the select statement but the record way does not seem to work for me what am I doing wrong here?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE Combined_name
IS
TYPE NameCombine IS RECORD(FIRST_NAME employees.FIRST_NAME%TYPE, LAST_NAME  
employees.LAST_NAME%TYPE, Combined_NAME employees.LAST_NAME%TYPE);

BEGIN 

SELECT
emp.FIRST_NAME,
emp.LAST_NAME,
emp.FIRST_NAME +' '+ emp.LAST_NAME
INTO 
 NameCombine.FIRST_NAME, 
 NameCombine.LAST_NAME,
 NameCombine.Combined_NAME
FROM 
EMPLOYEES emp;
dbms_output.put_line( NameCombine.FIRST_NAME );
END;
```

Website with similar syntax example as above:
http://plsql-tutorial.com/plsql-records.htm

Errors

```
Error(7,1): PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
Error(12,2): PLS-00330: invalid use of type name or subtype name
Error(14,34): PL/SQL: ORA-00904: : invalid identifier
Error(17,1): PL/SQL: Statement ignored
Error(17,23): PLS-00330: invalid use of type name or subtype name
```

Thank you in advance for your feedback.

Comment: Just offhand: You declared a `type` called `NameCombine`. You need to declare a variable of that type and select into that variable. For example: TYPE NameCombine_T IS RECORD...; NameCombine NameCombine_T; BEGIN ...

Comment: 1. You didnt declare a variable 2. You have declared a record type, it can hold one row only, so you have to use where filter to filter single row into the record variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This compilation error usually occurs when a datatype or subtype specifier was mistakenly used in place of a constant, variable, or expression.

When you Declare something as Type in PL/SQl, what you do is, create a custom data type.  you cannot be assigning values to a data type. You need to first create a variable of that custom type and then you can assign values to it.

```
  TYPE NameCombine IS RECORD(FIRST_NAME employees.FIRST_NAME%TYPE, LAST_NAME  
employees.LAST_NAME%TYPE, Combined_NAME employees.LAST_NAME%TYPE);

NameCombineVar NameCombine;

...

INTO 
 NameCombineVar.FIRST_NAME, 
 NameCombineVar.LAST_NAME,
 NameCombineVar.Combined_NAME
```

Answer (score 0):

1)  You need to ensure the combined name will have maximum or less length of `last_name` ,
or else it raise numeric value error
2)  Oracle doesn't have `+' '+` format to append ,
 instead use `emp.first_name||' 'emp.last_name` 
3)
Your code will work only for a single row data, or use `rownum = 1` in the where condition in the query.
4) declare an object for the `record` type you've created.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
PROCEDURE Combined_name
IS
     TYPE NAMECOMBINE 
     IS RECORD(
               FIRST_NAME employees.FIRST_NAME%TYPE,
               LAST_NAME employees.LAST_NAME%TYPE,
               COMBINED_NAME EMPLOYEES.LAST_NAME%TYPE
               );
     obj NAMECOMBINE;
BEGIN
     SELECT emp.FIRST_NAME,emp.LAST_NAME,emp.FIRST_NAME||' '||emp.LAST_NAME
     INTO OBJ.FIRST_NAME,OBJ.LAST_NAME,OBJ.Combined_NAME
     FROM EMPLOYEES EMP
     WHERE ROWNUM = 1;
     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( OBJ.FIRST_NAME );
END;
```

/

if you need to display records for multiple rows, you have `bulk collect into` clause as follows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
PROCEDURE Combined_name
is
     TYPE NameCombine IS
     RECORD
     (
          FIRST_NAME    VARCHAR2(20),
          LAST_NAME     VARCHAR2(20),
          Combined_NAME VARCHAR2(20));
     obj NameCombine;
     CURSOR test_cur
     IS
     SELECT emp.FIRST_NAME,emp.LAST_NAME,emp.FIRST_NAME||' '||emp.LAST_NAME
     FROM EMPLOYEES EMP;
     type test_rec_arr IS TABLE OF NameCombine INDEX BY pls_integer;
     test_rec test_rec_arr;
BEGIN
     OPEN test_cur;
     LOOP
          FETCH test_cur bulk collect INTO test_rec limit 10;
          FOR i IN test_rec.first..test_rec.last
          LOOP
               dbms_output.put_line(test_rec(i).FIRST_NAME);
          END LOOP;
          EXIT
     WHEN test_rec.count = 0;
     END LOOP;
     CLOSE test_cur;
END;
```